# uninstall sklearn in ML azure studio

Tags: python, installation, scikit-learn, uninstallation

i am trying to uninstall the sklean package from my ML studio, since it is [depricated](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Fix%20The%20Error%20For%20The%20Main%20Use%20Cases) and i believe it is the reason why i am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics' has no attribute 'mean_absolute_percentage_error'
```

i run the command:

```
!pip uninstall sklearn
```

but get an non-pop-up:

[image]

How can i prompt azure ML studio to proceed with the unistallation, since i cannot write the y?

Answer (score 0):

wiw `pip freeze` you can check the versions of packages, which returns this for the depricated package:

```
sklearn==0.0.post1
```

i have uninstalled it using the following command:

```
!pip uninstall -y sklearn
```

then istalled the correct package:

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.24
```

and my problem is solved!
Now i can use the `plot.plot_model_fit()` function without running into the aformentioned error.